# Software that can automatically login to a website, perform tasks and take screenshots?

Tags: macos, software-rec, autocomplete

Does anyone know of software that can be configured to automatically login to a website, perform tasks, and take screenshots at regular intervals? Preferably Mac-compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [FakeApp](http://fakeapp.com/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/).

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxDOlhysFcM) of it in action, it's actually a really neat tool.

Answer (score 1):

[iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/) can probably do what you need.  We use it in a commercial environment and it is very effective.

Comment: I've been checking out iMacros - I think that I can make it work if I used it in conjunction with a screen capture program

Answer (score 0):

Since "performing tasks" can mean so many different things, there most likely isn't a program out there, that would fully satisfy your needs. There are programs automatically logging you in (LastPass is a good example), there are programs taking screenshots, but if you want a all-in-one solution you probably need to let somebody write that software for you (or do it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to script it,[watir](http://watir.com) might do everything you need. Not sure if it does real screen shots or just captures of the HTML though.

Answer (score 0):

I use AutoHotkey to do this.
This is an example of a script that logs into a website.

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20195